# Failed to start Quarkus application

Tags: startup, quarkus

I have moved my Quarkus app to a new env and it will not start there. It works localy and on a AzureVM.

I have started the application with :`quarkus.debug.print-startup-times`

stackTrace   :

```
2022-02-22 11:02:29,889 Build step LoggingResourceProcessor.setupLoggingStaticInit completed in: 5ms
2022-02-22 11:02:29,895 Build step HttpSecurityProcessor.setupAuthenticationMechanisms completed in: 2ms
2022-02-22 11:02:29,899 Build step VertxCoreProcessor.ioThreadDetector completed in: 4ms
2022-02-22 11:02:29,900 Build step BlockingOperationControlBuildStep.blockingOP completed in: 0ms
2022-02-22 11:02:29,911 Build step MutinyProcessor.buildTimeInit completed in: 10ms
2022-02-22 11:02:29,953 Build step QuarkusSecurityCommonProcessor.registerPasswordProvider completed in: 41ms
2022-02-22 11:02:29,957 Build step DataSourcesExcludedFromHealthChecksProcessor.produceBean completed in: 3ms
2022-02-22 11:02:29,985 Build step SmallRyeOpenApiProcessor.classLoaderHack completed in: 28ms
2022-02-22 11:02:29,992 Build step SmallRyeContextPropagationProcessor.buildStatic completed in: 6ms
2022-02-22 11:02:29,994 Build step SmallRyeHealthProcessor.build completed in: 1ms
2022-02-22 11:02:29,995 Build step AgroalProcessor.generateDataSourceSupportBean completed in: 0ms
2022-02-22 11:02:29,995 Build step NativeImageConfigBuildStep.build completed in: 0ms
2022-02-22 11:02:29,998 Build step SecurityProcessor.gatherSecurityChecks completed in: 2ms
2022-02-22 11:02:29,999 Build step SyntheticBeansProcessor.initStatic completed in: 0ms
2022-02-22 11:02:30,022 Build step SmallRyeMetricsProcessor.registerMetricsFromAnnotatedMethods completed in: 22ms
2022-02-22 11:02:30,198 Build step ArcProcessor.generateResources completed in: 176ms
2022-02-22 11:02:30,201 Build step ResteasyCommonProcessor.setupResteasyInjection completed in: 2ms
2022-02-22 11:02:30,204 Build step SmallRyeMetricsProcessor.build completed in: 3ms
2022-02-22 11:02:30,335 Build step ResteasyStandaloneBuildStep.staticInit completed in: 130ms
2022-02-22 11:02:30,340 Build step SmallRyeMetricsProcessor.createRoute completed in: 4ms
2022-02-22 11:02:30,358 Build step BootstrapConfigSetupBuildStep.setupBootstrapConfig completed in: 16ms
2022-02-22 11:02:30,359 Build step QuarkusSecurityCommonProcessor.registerPasswordProviderForNative completed in: 0ms
2022-02-22 11:02:30,360 Build step NettyProcessor.eagerlyInitClass completed in: 0ms
2022-02-22 11:02:30,361 Build step VertxCoreProcessor.createVertxThreadFactory completed in: 0ms
2022-02-22 11:02:30,361 Build step VertxCoreProcessor.createVertxContextHandlers completed in: 0ms
2022-02-22 11:02:30,362 Build step SmallRyeMetricsProcessor.dropRegistriesAtShutdown completed in: 0ms
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/oas/rekvirent/quarkus-app/lib/main/org.jboss.slf4j.slf4j-jboss-logmanager-1.1.0.Final.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/oas/rekvirent/quarkus-app/lib/main/ch.qos.logback.logback-classic-1.2.9.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory]
2022-02-22 11:02:30,786 Build step VaultProcessor.init completed in: 424ms
2022-02-22 11:02:30,796 Build step SmallRyeMetricsProcessor.registerBaseAndVendorMetrics completed in: 9ms
Feb 22, 2022 11:02:29 AM io.quarkus.config
WARN: Unrecognized configuration key "%s" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo
Feb 22, 2022 11:02:30 AM org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n
INFO: RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class MyDemoApplication
Feb 22, 2022 11:02:30 AM io.netty.resolver.dns.DefaultDnsServerAddressStreamProvider
WARN: Default DNS servers: [/8.8.8.8:53, /8.8.4.4:53] (Google Public DNS as a fallback)
Feb 22, 2022 11:02:31 AM io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager run
ERROR: Failed to start application (with profile prod)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:710)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The new env does not have have Connection to internet , could that be a problem ?

Comment: Can you try starting the application with `quarkus.debug.print-startup-times` and pasting the result? 
That should give some indication about where the problem lies...

Comment: I have edited my post, added stacktrace with `quarkus.debug.print-startup-times=true`

Comment: Interesting. Do you have code that tries to do a network call?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. My Connection   to database  was not correct .
Quarkus is starting up now, thanks